# How do I execute model-related code only once in CakePhp 2.3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

**What I want:**
I have a model `Version` with a member function `update`. I want this member function called once, every time a page is loaded.

**What I did so far:**
My current approach is to add the line

```
ClassRegistry::init('Version')->update();
```

into the `beforeFilter()` method of `AppController`

A previous solution was, to put the following code into `app/Config/bootstrap.php`:

```
App::uses('CakeEventManager', 'Event');
CakeEventManager::instance()->attach(
    function(){
        AppModel::getSingletonModel('Version')->update();
    },
    'Controller.startup'
);
```

(`getSingletonModel` does what it sounds like - get a singleton instance of the model)

**The Problem:**
Both solutions work, *but* if several controllers are loaded, the function is called several times. Which eats up resources.
Also, `ClassRegistry` has not been loaded, when `bootstrap.php` is executed. So I can't directly call the function there.

**Additional Information:**
The (technical) reason for several Controllers being called seems to be, that in a dashboard view some content is generated by calling `$this->requestAction`.

**My Question:**
Is there a way in CakePHP to call the function only once, like the file `app/Config/bootstrap.php`, but *after* the models are loaded?

**Some Background:**
I'm developing a project in CakePHP 2.3 together with other developers.
I'm working on an autoupdate-system, where developers can add some code, which they want to run once (e.g. to adapt the database for added functionality).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on what you're after, but perhaps what you are looking for is [Migrations](https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations). You can use the `after` method of a migration file to modify the content of the database. Once a migration file has been run it is logged in the database so that it is not called again.

Comment: That is an interesting plugin, thanks. Unfortunately, as far as I can see, it does not do the updates automatically. I edited my question. I hope, it gets a little clearer what I'm after.

Comment: I'm still confused as to what you actually want to achieve. Can you not call this in the `beforeFilter()` method of `AppController` as this will only get called once per page load?

Comment: Another question is why are multiple controllers being called on a single request?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja I hadn't tried that, because I didn't know that function existed. The [description](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks) looks like what I need. Unfortunately a short test showed, that this is also called per controller call, not once per request.

Comment: @Derek some content is loaded via `requestAction()` into a dashboard. Since this is an old project with lots of changes in who is working on it, I do not really know, why this solution was chosen. I just try to believe, that there is a good reason.

Comment: @Till `beforeFilter` will only be called once per request, using `requestAction` is causing multiple requests to be made. I think your only solution will be to replace the use of `requestAction` as otherwise I think what you are trying to achieve is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just asked the wrong question.

I made it work by loading `ClassRegistry` in the `bootstrap.php`

```
App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');
ClassRegistry::init('Version')->update();
```